# Call templated constructor from non-templated constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

Let's say I have a class similar to:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    MyClass(const MyClass<U>&); // Not a copy constructor, as template.

    // How to delegate to above constructor?
    MyClass(const MyClass& a) : MyClass<T>(a) {}

    // ...
};
```

How to delegate the copy constructors to a (conversion) template constructor?

The code above results in a delegation cycle.

Comment: Normally, template argument deduction should be sufficient. The example is unclear because `MyClass` appears to inconsistently be a `class` or a `class` template.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. `MyClass` is a template and has a template argument `T`. It has a converting constructor `template <typename U> MyClass(const MyClass<U>&);` and OP wants to delegate to that from copy constructor. No idea if this is possible tho.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux MyClass is a class template with T being a template argument.

Comment: @BlueCannonBall Then update your question to make it clear. Provide a minimal example that compile except for the problematic constructor. I think that the easier workaround would be to have a "kind" of copy constructor with an extra argument.

Comment: Try `: MyClass::MyClass<T>(a) {}`

Answer (score 1):

If the guess from @Yksisarvinen is correct then something like that should do:

```
template <class T> class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const MyClass& a) : MyClass(a, true) {}

    template <class U>
    MyClass(const MyClass<U>& a) : MyClass(a, false) {}

private:
    template <class U>
    MyClass(const MyClass<U>& a, bool sameClass) 
    { 
        /* real code here */ 
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can remove second copy constructor and put a default value for `sameClass` if you prefer (and make that constructor public).

Comment: I would use a dummy tag instead of `bool`. `std::is_same_v<T, U>` has the information anyway, if required.

Comment: @Jarod42 What do you mean by dummy tag?

Comment: @Jarod42 Not a bad idea to use a dummy tag... I just made as simple as possible.

Comment: @BlueCannonBall: I mean using some `struct dummy_tag{};` and then [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8dxYn7P4j). `bool sameClass` has a meaning (which might be used wrongly).